# MySql LEFT JOIN returns only one NULL row from the other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySql.
table1:

```
id account_no 
1  123 
2  124 
3  125 
4  126 
5  127
```

table2:

```
id amount
1  200
1  300
2  400
3  300
2  100
```

My desired output is:

```
account_no total_amount
123  500
124  500
125  300
126  0
127  0
```

My query is as follows

```
SELECT a.account_no AS 'account_no', IFNULL(SUM(b.amount),0) AS 'total_amount'
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY b.id ORDER BY a.account_no
```

But with this query I'm getting only this

```
account_no total_amount
123  500
124  500
125  300
126  0
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
SELECT a.account_no AS 'account_no', IFNULL(SUM(b.amount),0) AS 'total_amount'
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.account_no ORDER BY a.account_no
```

Instead of `b.bid`, which has only `3` unique value to group use `a.account_no`, which will have all unique account.

Let me know for any query. :)

Comment: Thanks. That helped:)

Answer (score 0):

Thats why you `GROUP BY b.id`. In your case b.id id null for a.id 126 and 127 is `null` and will be grouped.

The result of your join for the last two lines will be:

```
a.id account_no b.id total amount
4  126 null null 
5  127 null null
```

and these rows are grouped to one row.

Comment: sorry i dont get it. I have GROUP BY b.id in my query

Comment: @rin2 and this will group both lines to one line because it groups all lines which has `b.id = null` to one line.

Answer (score 0):

your query is perfect, except the group by clause,

```
SELECT a.account_no AS 'account_no', IFNULL(SUM(b.amount),0) AS 'total_amount'
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.account_no ORDER BY a.account_no
```

Left join return all data from left table, with null if right table has no data, when using group by you need to give key column from left table, because group by gets unique rows

please have a look, let me know if any problem.

Thanks
Amit